# Temporarily replace container with other container

Tags: c, pygtk, gtk, gtk2

I'm currently writing a GTK app that consists of a single window with a `GtkListView` and a button. When the user presses the button, some form shall appear that allows to insert new data to be appended to the list.

Instead of opening a new window for the form, I'd like it to temporarily replace the `GtkListView`. I'm pretty new to GTK, so I'd like to know whether there's an idiomatic way to do this.

My current guess is that I have to add a notebook with two hidden tabs, one for the list and one for the form. Whenever the button is pressed, I emit the `focus-tab` signal to switch to the form tab.

Is there a better way to temporarily replace a `GtkListView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a notebook to create temporary widgets, you can just use a simple box
What I use is the following:

```
  # displaying the list view
  container = gtk.VBox()
  container.add(tree_view)

  # removing the treeview and adding a form
  container.remove(tree_view)
  container.add(form)
  form.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [`gtk_container_add`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-add) & [`gtk_container_remove`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-remove) in the button's callback to achieve this. Add your first view to a container. On user click on the button, remove the first view & add the next one. And vice-versa. Make sure to add a reference to the widget before add to the container because if widget is removed from container & if there are no references to the widget, the widget is destroyed. Here is a sample in C for your reference:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GtkWidget *view0;
static GtkWidget *view1;
static GtkWidget *frame;
static int current_view_id;

static GtkWidget *
create_view0 (void)
{
  GtkWidget *scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window),
                  GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
  GtkWidget *view0_content = gtk_label_new ("Here is first view");
  gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW
                     (scrolled_window), view0_content);
  gtk_widget_show_all (scrolled_window);
  return scrolled_window;
}

static GtkWidget *
create_view1 (void)
{
  GtkWidget *scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);
  GtkWidget *view1_content = gtk_label_new ("Here is next view");
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window),
                  GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
  gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW
                     (scrolled_window), view1_content);
  gtk_widget_show_all (scrolled_window);
  return scrolled_window;
}

static gboolean
change_view (GtkWidget * button, gpointer data)
{
  (void) data;

  if (current_view_id == 0)
    {
      gtk_button_set_label (GTK_BUTTON (button), "Prev");
      gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER (frame), view0);
      /* Need to add reference as container will own widget ref */
      /* If gtk_container_remove is called with widget's last ref, widget is destroyed */
      g_object_ref (view1);
      gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (frame), view1);
      current_view_id = 1;
    }
  else
    {
      gtk_button_set_label (GTK_BUTTON (button), "Next");
      gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER (frame), view1);
      /* Need to add reference as container will own widget ref */
      /* If gtk_container_remove is called with widget's last ref, widget is destroyed */
      g_object_ref (view0);
      gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (frame), view0);
      current_view_id = 0;
    }

  return FALSE;
}

int
main (void)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *vbox;
  GtkWidget *label;
  GtkWidget *button;

  gtk_init (NULL, NULL);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 5);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);

  frame = gtk_frame_new (" Sample for view change ");
  view0 = create_view0 ();
  view1 = create_view1 ();

  /* Need to add reference as container will own widget ref */
  /* If gtk_container_remove is called with widget's last ref, widget is destroyed */
  g_object_ref (view0);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (frame), view0);

  label = gtk_label_new ("View change sample");
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Next");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (change_view), NULL);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), label, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), frame, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!